# I get the cp cannot stat permission denied error when I try to deploy my Angular project using Gitlab runner

Tags: angular, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an Angular 11 project with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` that I'm trying to deploy:

```
stages:
  - dependencies
  - build
  # - test
  - deploy
  - deploy-development

dependencies:
  stage: dependencies
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - npm ci

build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod

deploy-development:
  stage: deploy-development
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
  script:
    - cp -r dist/my-website/* /var/www/my-website-dev/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
    - cp -r dist/my-website/* /var/www/my-website/
```

And I'm pushing to the `dev` branch.

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ cp -r dist/my-website/* /var/www/my-website-dev/
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/3rdpartylicenses.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/4.51564c68d90fd018ee9b.js': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/assets': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/favicon.ico': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/index.html': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/main.9cb75e6b25a9624eb401.js': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/polyfills.9f4018ee1bb21acbee08.js': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/runtime.338ea4d131f911332271.js': Permission denied
cp: cannot stat '/var/www/my-website-dev/styles.3cd4d62216b0053c818d.css': Permission denied
```

Comment: Does `/var/www/my-website-dev` even exist? Try `mkdir -p var/www/my-website-dev` before?